# deploy angular to heroku with nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I have a problem getting the project to heroku
On the site I only see the word 'hello' through the index.html file but it does not move on

think I have no problems, but when I try to connect i see only hello and in the heroku logs - - tail i get on all request 
status: 200

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Myapp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <p>hello</p>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

here  it's print only the hello in the screen form the file and doesnt continu to app root

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
require('../mongoose/db/database')
const Menu = require('../mongoose/model/menu')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/my-pizza-app')))


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../', 'index.html'));

});

app.get('/meals', async (req,res) =>{
  try{
  const menu = await Menu.find({})
  if(!menu){
     return res.status(400).send()
  }
  res.status(201).send(menu)
  console.log(menu)

} catch(e) {
  res.status(500).send(e)
  console.log(e)
}
})

module.exports = app
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-[enter image description here][1]app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "src/server/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node src/server/app.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev": "nodemon src/server/app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "~12.4.0",
    "npm": "~6.9.0"
  }
}
```

I searched everywhere and could not find the solution

Comment: Check browser console & see if there are any errors.

Comment: dont have error